# Polynomial equation $f(x)f(2x^2)=f(2x^3+x)$

Tags: polynomials, functional-equations

> Find all polynomials $f(x)$, for which $f(x)f(2x^2)=f(2x^3+x)$.

I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: I think this question should be reopened, as [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2600903) question was closed as being a duplicate of this current one. (So a "good" question is a duplicate of a "bad" question...)