# If $f(x)$ Polynomial with real coefficient and $f(0)=1$, $f(2)+f(3)=125$ and $f(x)*f(2x^2)=f(2x^3+x)$ then what is the value of $f(5)$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

If $f(x)$ Polynomial with real coefficient and $f(0)=1$, $f(2)+f(3)=125$
and
$f(x)*f(2x^2)=f(2x^3+x)$

then what is the value of $f(5)$?

.

What I tried
$$f(0)=1$$
put x=1 $$f(1)*f(2)=f(3)$$
put x=2 $$f(2)*f(8)=f(18)$$

from this approach, I cant find f(5). Please Suggest a method to solve.

Comment: I edit the question. That's all i know about the question

Comment: Trying $x=1$ and $x=2$ is probably not enough. You should try more.

Comment: does * represent multipication operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a somewhat unfulfilling solution.

According to [Solve $f(x)f(2x^2) = f(2x^3+x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2600903/solve-fxf2x2-f2x3x), the polynomial $f(x)$ is of the form $f(x)=(x^2+1)^n$ for some $n$.

Using $f(2)+f(3)=125$ we obtain $n=2$, so $f(x)=(x^2+1)^2$. Plugging in $x=5$ we conclude
$$f(5)=(5^2+1)^2=26^2=676.$$

Comment: I check the https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2600903/solve-fxf2x2-f2x3x page. How to get that $f(x)=(x^2+1)^n$ is the form of $f(x)$. Would you please explain it to me. You can give me Hint also.

Comment: @PankajSolanki The accepted solution is quite complete and doesn't use any advanced facts. If you have difficulty understanding a specific point I would be glad to help you out.

Comment: I got my answer. Thanks for Help.